# Group by and then sum value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am struggling to get this going and could need some help. I have the following setup:

```
Order     Item      Material     Value
 22        1          100         27,5
 22        1          200         27,5
 22        1          300         27,5
 22        2          100         33
 22        3          500        101
 26        1          500         88
 26        1          600         88
```

I have duplicate values becaue of the `Material`, so I want to group by `Order`, `Item` and `Value` and then calculate the total `Value` in a DAX measure.

After grouping:

```
Order     Item     Value
 22        1        27,5
 22        2        33
 22        3       101
 26        1        88
```

The final Value:

```
Total Measure = 249,5
```

I tried the following DAX expression for the `Total Measure`:

```
Total Measure = Summarize('Table1'; 'Table1'[Order]; 'Table1'[Item]; "Sum Value:"; Sum('Table1'[Value]))
```

It gives me the error:

> Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value

So I tried:

```
Total Measure = Sumx('Table1'; Summarize('Table1'; 'Table1'[Order]; 'Table1'[Item]; "Sum Value:"; Sum('Table1'[Value])))
```

But this didnt work either. For every help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should be what you are looking for

```
Measure1 =
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table1;
        Table1[Order];
        Table1[Item];
        Table1[Value];
        "TotalSum"; SUM ( Table1[Value] )
    );
    [Value]
)
```

Comment: Ah thx exactly what I was looking for. Works perfect, with all the filters. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can simply use the [`VALUES` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/values-function-dax) instead of `SUMMARIZE`.

```
Total Measure = SUMX ( VALUES ( Table1[Value] ), [Value] )
```

This iterates over each unique `Value` and adds `Value` to the sum.

Comment: I checked the `Values()` function but this doesnt work for my case, because a different order could have the same value as another one and the distinctcount would eliminate it